# Add 1 or add pair of Powerline adapters

Tags: networking

I have 2 rooms which WiFi cannot reach. I am now using a pair of Belkin power line adapters between my router (Ethernet port 1 to power-line adapter) and my PC (power-line adapter to Ethernet port of PC) in room one.

Now I want to get connection to my laptop in room 2. I was told that I can just add another power adapter unit and the 3 power adapters will just form a network. But this will mean some degradation. I can see one reason is that my PC and my laptop will both be connected to port 1 of my router.

The other option is to add another pair of power-line adapters which connects Ethernet port 2 of my router to the laptop in room 2. This way my PC will be using port 1 and my laptop will be using port 2. However the 2 pairs of power line adapters may interfere each other.

Can some one help with these 2 options. Are they valid? if so which way should I go?

Comment: "I can see one reason is that my PC and my laptop will both be connected to port 1 of my router." - That isn't the reason for the degradation.

Comment: IMO The ideal solution is to ditch the adapters altogether and add another wireless access point, if possible. But, given your options, I'd be inclined to say using multiple pairs of power line adapters is the better option (meaning, for each device, router -> adapter -> adapter -> end device) ... If you share the network connection of one device, that means that device will always need to be powered on in order for device 2 to work. You don't need another adapter to do this, just 2 NICs on the sharing device. Also, can you post the model numbers of the power line adapter(s) you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two pairs of powerline adapters will "interfere" (more specifically, compete for time on the medium) with each other. Powerline adapters — even a single pair — squeeze every last drop of available bandwidth out of the power wiring in your house. All of the wiring in your house used as a single "channel". So if you add another pair of adapters, they're competing with the other pair for time on the single shared medium (shared channel) which is your home's electrical wiring.

The bandwidth that the powerline adapters can get out of your home's wiring is the real bottleneck, not the single 1Gbps Ethernet LAN port you're plugging one of them into on the router.

Adding a single powerline adapter is almost certainly better than adding a pair.